# Atualizações no código não sendo executadas durante o Debug, Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debug, wildfly

Eu trabalho com Eclipse e WildFly. Bom, minha questão é simples:
Eu fiz uma alteração qualquer no código, porém, ao fazer o Debug observei que essa alteração não estava sendo executada, como se o Eclipse executasse sempre a versão antiga do código, ignorando as minhas alterações.
Com esse problema eu não consegui testar minhas alterações no código, eu tive que fazer um commit, e outro desenvolvedor atualizou o código com as minhas alterações e conseguiu testar.

Eu tentei fazer build, clean, baixar de novo o projeto, porém, nenhuma das tentativas funcionou

Alguém já passou por algo parecido, se sim, como procedeu ?

Obrigado, Atenciosamente

Answer (score 1):

Já passei por algo parecido várias vezes, o problema sempre era que o projeto tinha que ser re-implantado (fazer o deploy de novo) no servidor de aplicação. No caso, é bom dar um restart na JVM para que o class loader execute novamente também.